# Error when reading from csv: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, networking

I keep getting an error regarding my list having no attribute 'strip'.

I'm trying to send cisco cmds to switches listed in a csv. I pull from the csv, have the csv reader read it, and then do a row. Sometimes if I play with the indents only the last csv value is used.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import pandas
import getpass
import csv
from csv import DictReader

usr = input("Enter your Username: ")
passwd = getpass.getpass('Please Enter Password: ')
command = input('Enter Cmd You Wish to Send: ')


with open('Scripts/SWList.csv', 'r') as csv_list:
    switches = csv.reader(csv_list)
    for row in switches:
        Cisco_Switches = {
            'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
            'host': row,
            'username': usr,
            'password': passwd
        }
        device = ConnectHandler(**Cisco_Switches)
        output = device.send_command(command)

    if ('% Unknown command' in output):
            (
                print('Error Sending Command for ' + row + '!')
                )
    else:
            (
                print('Command Sent Successfully to ' + row + '...')
                )

filename = 'Scripts/' + row + '.txt'
save_file = open(filename, "a")
save_file.write(output)
save_file.close()
device.disconnect()`
```

If I move `device = connecthandler(**Cisco_Switches)` to the left it will run, but only for the last value in the csv.

CSV formatting below:

```
IP
172.16.X.X
172.16.X.X
172.16.X.X
```

```
Error:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Networking\Scripts\ConfigMultSwitches.py", line 21, in <module>   
    device = ConnectHandler(**Cisco_Switches)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\netmiko\ssh_dispatcher.py", line 365, in ConnectHandler
    return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 312, in __init__
    self.host = host.strip()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the whole error traceback message.

Comment: Sorry, im real new to posting here. i edited the question, the best i could.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and check out how to ask a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Small thing, the networking tag is probably not appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

The row returned by the csv.reader call is a list, not a string.  The split method need to be called on a string.  You should be referencing the string itself in the list (I assume the zero index?).  Try 'host': row[0].  That's assuming the host is in the first column of the CSV table.